# Open PDF in a new window on image click

Tags: php, html

I want to open a PDF file in a new browser window when user clicks on the image. I saw the other links but not found what I am looking for.

Any PHP/HTML way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<a href="path-to-my.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="image.gif" alt="my shiny PDF" border="0"/></a>
```

Comment: you forgot the alt attribute, which is required by xhtml strict ;)

Comment: Ah, all you strict guys... :) Fine, I'll add it ;)

Comment: Since there is a target attribute and a border attribute, it can't be Strict. The attribute is mandatory in all versions though. The space before the / that is required by the HTML compatibility guidelines is missing though.

Comment: The alt attribute’s pretty important for blind users in this case. There’s nothing else that indicates where the link goes.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="mypdf.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="image.png" width="320" height="240" alt="My Super Awesome PDF" /></a>
```

Comment: In a non-example, the alt attribute would have a useful value though. A link with nothing to identify the target isn't very helpful.

Comment: Changed it. Thought it would be obvious to most. Do we really have to chew someones food?

Comment: This **is** a question at the level of "Opening a link in a new window".